# Union with inner join, mysql error

Tags: mysql, join, union

```
(SELECT * FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable INNER JOIN new_apps ON 
new_apps.trackId=dtable.trackId WHERE primaryGenreName='Games'
AND composed='1' AND new_apps.top>0)
UNION (SELECT * FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable WHERE primaryGenreName='Games')
LIMIT 12
```

error:

```
#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

on new_apps there are fields that are not in app_detailsvvv, how can I mask for the second query in the union somehow.

edit:

```
(SELECT dtable.* FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable INNER JOIN new_apps ON new_apps.trackId=dtable.trackId WHERE primaryGenreName='Games' AND composed='1' AND new_apps.top>0) UNION (SELECT * FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable WHERE primaryGenreName='Games') LIMIT 12
```

worked yet when I add `ORDER BY new_apps.top ASC` I get this new error:

```
#1250 - Table 'new_apps' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
```

Comment: Your query doesn't really make sense.  It is choosing 12 arbitrary rows from the `app_detailsvvv` table where `primaryGenreName='Games'`.  I suspect you want to prioritize the returns, but `union` *definitely* jumbles up the rows.

Comment: I want to select order by top asc on which only the top trackIds are available, if there is none, run out with pagination then select on app_detailsvvv

Comment: @ibennet . . . That is what the query in my answer does.  It is not what your query does, even when fixed for the number of columns in the `union`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(SELECT dtable.* FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable INNER JOIN new_apps ON 
new_apps.trackId=dtable.trackId WHERE primaryGenreName='Games'
AND composed='1' AND new_apps.top>0)
UNION (SELECT * FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable WHERE primaryGenreName='Games')
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: worked, now when I add: ORDER BY new_apps.top ASC this error comes out: Table 'new_apps' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a `union`, just a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT dtable.*
FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable LEFT OUTER JOIN
     new_apps
     ON new_apps.trackId = dtable.trackId and
        composed = '1' AND new_apps.top > 0
WHERE dtable.primaryGenreName = 'Games'
LIMIT 12;
```

Hmmm, this might return duplicates, which you can get rid of using `select distinct dtable.*`.

But wait.  This query really isn't doing anything other than returning all the rows in the first table.  I suspect that you want to return 12 rows, with a priority given to the ones with a match.  If that is the case, then the query you want is:

```
SELECT dtable.*
FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable LEFT OUTER JOIN
     new_apps
     ON new_apps.trackId = dtable.trackId
WHERE dtable.primaryGenreName = 'Games'
GROUP BY dtable.trackId   <-- or whatever the unique id is on the table
ORDER BY (composed = '1' AND new_apps.top > 0) desc
LIMIT 12;
```